Multivariable chain rule on composition $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$
Let $w\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ and $h\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be the maps $w(x,y)=(e^y, xy)$ and $h(x,y)=x^2+y$. Determine the composite function $h\circ w$ and determine the partial derivatives $D_1(h\circ w)$ and $D_2(h\circ w)$ using the chain rule.
So it is easy to see that $$(h\circ w)(x,y)=h(w(x,y))=h(e^y, xy)=e^{2y}+xy,$$ so we get that $$D_1(h\circ w)=y \quad \text{and} \quad D_2(h\circ w)=2e^{2y}+x.$$ However I'm asked to show this using the chain rule, which in this case, using facts known from the book, would be $$D_1(h\circ w)(x,y)=h'(w(x,y))\cdot D_1w(x,y)$$ if we only consider the first partial derivative. However I'm confused as to what $D_1w(x,y)$ is since $w$ does not map into $\mathbb R$. Am I missing something here/can someone explain the definition?

You need to interpret that $\cdot$ as a product of matrices (of size $2\times 1$ with $1\times 2$). Can you figure out these matrices and carry out the product?

The way I interpret $D_1f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ for some map $f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is to differentiate $x\mapsto f(x, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ in the normal way. Hence I don't know what this means since $w\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.

The same limit definition carries through for $f$ taking values in $\Bbb{R}^m$. Equivalently, you can view it as $Df_x(e_1)$, i.e the derivative $Df_x$, which is a linear map $\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$, evaluated on the vector $e_1$.

Anyway to be super explicit, if $f:\Bbb{R}^m\to \Bbb{R}$ and $g:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$ are differentiable, then $D_i(f\circ g)(x) =\sum\limits_{j=1}^m (D_jf)(g(x))\cdot (D_ig^j)(x)$. So this is the formula you need to apply.

Given a function $\mathbf{f}:U\subseteq \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R^m$, defined on an open set $U$ of the euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, the jacobian matrix of $f$ is the $m\times n$ matrix of partial derivatives constructed as follows.
We can surely write $\mathbf{f}=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$, where each $f_i$ is a map that goes from $U$ to $\mathbb R$. Then if $\mathbf{x}=(x^1,\ldots,x^n)\in U$, the jacobian matrix of $f$ is
$$ J\mathbf{f}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x^1} & \ldots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x^n} \\
\vdots & \ddots &  \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x^1} & \ldots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x^n} \\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad (J\mathbf{f})_{ij}=\frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x^j}$$
Just note that if $m=1$ then the jacobian of $f$ is the usual gradient, i.e. the vector of partial derivatives.
Jacobian matrices obey the usual chain rule. If $\mathbf f:U\subseteq \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbf g:V\subseteq \mathbb R^m\longrightarrow \mathbb R^k$, where $U$ and $V$ are open sets and $\mathbf f(U)\subseteq V$, then $\mathbf g\circ\mathbf f$ is a well defined function from $U$ to $\mathbb R^k$ whose jacobian matrix satisfies
$$J(\mathbf g\circ\mathbf f)(\mathbf x)=J\mathbf g(\mathbf f(\mathbf x))\:J\mathbf f(\mathbf x)$$
In your specific case:
\begin{align}
\nabla (h\circ w)(x,y)&=\nabla h(w(x,y))Jw(x,y)
\\&=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(e^y,xy) & \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(e^y,xy) \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial w_1}{\partial x}(x,y) &  \frac{\partial w_1}{\partial y}(x,y)\\
\frac{\partial w_2}{\partial x}(x,y) &  \frac{\partial w_2}{\partial y}(x,y)\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=\begin{bmatrix}
2e^y & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 &  e^y\\
y &  x\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=\begin{bmatrix}
y & 2e^{2y}+x \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
So, as you already have established, we have proved that
\begin{align}
D_1(h\circ w)&=y\\D_2(h\circ w)&=2e^{2y}+x
\end{align}
using the chain rule.

It is sometimes easier if you use different variables. So, we want to compute the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)= h(e^y, xy)$, where $h(u,v)=u^2 + v$. The chain rule states that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}= 2u \cdot 0 + 1\cdot y = y
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=2u \cdot e^y + 1 \cdot x =2 e^{2y}+ x 
$$
